# [Q} Newbie to statistics, I'm not really getting the requirement for b) any ideas what this meant

Tags: statistics, statistics-bootstrap

Create a visualization that shows how many products are repeat purchases. Use the visualization to:
a) State which category of the variable repeat purchases has the most observations.

b) Explain whether the observations are balanced across categories of the variable repeat purchases

**For better context:** I have a dataset of 6 categories (observations) and number of products for each, the grand total is 1500 products.

**What I have tried:** calculating the stdev and mean, to test if the variable are clustered around the mean, but I was unable to visualize this properly on a bell curve.

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

It asks for a visualization, so I would make a bar chart. Then, if they were balanced, the graph should look like a uniform distribution. You can overlay one, although it's probably unnecessary since we know a uniform would have bars of equal heights.